# How can I compute $h'$ of $2$ on this?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I find the answer to this?

> Let $h(x)=\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$.
> Suppose that $f(2)=4$, $f'(2)=3$ and $f''(2)=6$. Compute $h'(2)$.

Right now I did it like this:
$$h(2)=1/2(1+3^2)(2(6))^{-1/2}$$ which equals to $$10/4\sqrt3$$ but apparently that's wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you find $h'(x)$ using one of the differentiation rules?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Looking at your value for $h'(2)$, my guess is that you're using the chain rule incorrectly, what did you get for $h'(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've most probably not applied the chain rule properly.
$$h(x)=\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$$
$$h'(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}}\right)\left(0+2f'(x)\right)\left(f''(x)\right)=\frac{2f'(x)f''(x)}{2\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}}$$

Ensure that you've understood how I got the above expression before making appropriate substitutions.